# How to conver a string value to an integer

Tags: java, parsing

I want to convert a string value to an integer but I can't. My statement checked

`=Integer.parseInt(input);`

has an error, please help and thanks a lot in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ass2a
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input,b;
        long checked;
        System.out.print("Please enter the 12 digit:");
        input = reader.nextLine();


        if(input.length() < 12)
        {
            System.out.println("The digit is less than 12.");
        }

        int one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twevle;
        checked =Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.println(checked);
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all use trim() on your input String.. Next, you re trying to seperate individual numbers(i think) use regex/subString/indexOf etc to seperate individual numbers and Integer.parseInt()

Comment: The cool thing with error messages is that you can read them to understand what the problem is, or post them if you can't understand them.

Comment: Java.Lang.NumberFormatException:

Comment: I can't understand this error.

Comment: @user3235248 - Its an Exception not an error (may be you should look into the differences). Next - "NumberFormatException" means your String cannot be converted (formatted) to a NUMBER (Specifically integer in your case because , the String value exceeds the int limit which is 2^32)

Comment: Hi all,thanks a lot. I have comprehended it finally.

Comment: @user3235248 check my answer and tell me if your problem is solved or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use      `checked =Long.parseLong(input);` instead of      `checked =Integer.parseInt(input);`

12 digit numbers are very large and so you can not store it in `int`.So you need to store in `Long`

Answer (score 0):

12 digits number is a really big number...Integer can't store it. That is you error - so you need another type to store the number.

I recommend you to use Long : Long.parseLong(input);

That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because the string value that you are giving as input is more than 2147483647. This is the max int can store (you can sysout Integer.MAX_VALUE to check this). If you intend to input a bigger number, may be you can use long (max value 9223372036854775807)

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // =2147483647 (2^31 - 1)

System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE); // =9223372036854775807 (2^63 - 1)
```

Depending on the input size, you might want to choose the correct data type.

Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is this line:

```
input = reader.nextLine();
```

try this:

```
 checked = Long.parseLong(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 checked= Long.parseLong(input)
```

instead of

```
Integer.parseInt
```

it can't handle a 12 digit long number

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected program(assuming that your trying to find whether a User-inputted number is less than 12 and displaying the number

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ass2a
{
public static void main(String []args)
{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    long input,b;
    long checked;
    System.out.print("Please enter the 12 digit:");
    input = reader.nextLong();



    if(String.valueOf(input).length() < 12)
    {
        System.out.println("The digit is less than 12.");
    }
  int one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twevle;
 checked =(long)(input);
       System.out.println(checked);
      }
}
```